# How to make a table of variables in a loop?

Tags: c

I want to follow the given code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
  char m[100]="Mirror",*p,*q;
  int i;
  p=m;
  q=p+strlen(m);
  printf("%d\n",strlen(m));
  printf("The value of s is: %c\n", &p);

   for(i=strlen(m)-1;i>=0;i--)
   {

       *q++=*(p+i);
       *q=0;
   }
   puts(m);
   return 0;
}
```

Here what i have started:

[image]

can someone show me how to follow the given variable so I will be able to solve similar questions?

I want to write a table that shows the value in each step. where the pointer points

Comment: No clue what you are asking. You show some code and a excel screen.

Comment: Just to write a table that shows the value in each step. where the pointer points...

Comment: Upvoting this, because I love questions about how to debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to learn how to use a debugger. But that's a too broad topic to cover here. (I really recommend it though)

The next best way is a simple printout.

```
for(i=strlen(m)-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    printf("i: %d\n*p: %s\n*q: %s\n\n", i, p, q);
    *q++=*(p+i);
    *q=0;
}
```

It's a bit ambiguous if you want to print the *string* that starts at the pointers or the *character*. If you want the latter, change to this:

```
    printf("i: %d\n*p: %c\n*q: %c\n\n", i, *p, *q);
```

Note that I **both** added asterisks **and** changed `%s` to `%c`.

If it is a big project. Consider writing to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. Just replace `printf(...` with `fprintf(stderr, ...` Or consider writing to a log file or something.

Comment: You sir, are a genius. I didn't even know what this question was about, and you got two upvotes and the selected answer.

Answer (score 2):

The loop "mirrors" the original text string, i.e. appends itself in reversed ordered.

It does that by

1. copy the last char to the end
2. copy the second last char to the end

and so on.

So in the loop, the string changes like:

```
Mirror
i = 5
Mirrorr
i = 4
Mirrorro
i = 3
Mirrorror
i = 2
Mirrorrorr
i = 1
Mirrorrorri
i = 0
MirrorrorriM
```

BTW:

This line:

```
printf("The value of s is: %c\n", &p);
```

is wrong. It tries to print a pointer using `%c` which is undefined behavior.

Did you want:

```
printf("The value of s is: %p\n", (void*)&p);
```